# Express JS with Node.JS

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean

I am having a problem with my website. I am running Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64 with node.js. For my website, whenever I go to the other pages on my website. It directs them to the 404 page even though I have a routing set for it.

Here is my server.js file:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use('/',express.static(__dirname + '/'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('view engine','html');


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

app.get('/resume', function(req, res){
    res.render('resume');
});

app.get('/contact', function(req, res){
    res.render('contact');
});

app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.status(404).render('404');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port 3000!');
});
```

For my other configurations for nginx, everything has been based from this guide here: https://code.lengstorf.com/deploy-nodejs-ssl-digitalocean/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for this. I have tried running this command:    `DEBUG=express:* node server.js` and it returned with an error containing this

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1257:14)
at listen (net.js:1293:10)
at Server.listen (net.js:1389:5)
at EventEmitter.listen (/apps/michaeluy.me/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:617:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (/apps/michaeluy.me/server.js:30:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
```

Now I simply changed 3000 to 5000 on my server.js file as seen here:

```
app.listen(5000, function () {
console.log('Listening on port 5000!');
});
```

and now. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your express static config and your route configurations express is expecting `index.html`, `resume.html` and `contact.html` in the views directory.

By default the express res.render() method expects your views in the `./views` folder: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.render

So your project should look like the following:

```
www
|-- views
|    |-- index.html 
|    |-- resume.html 
|    +-- contact.html
|-- node_modules
|    + ...
|-- index.js
+-- package.json
```

Comment: Hi dsandor,

Thanks for the answer. I actually have that setup correctly. Here is the github page where everything that I have is located: https://github.com/MichaelUyy/michaeluyme

Answer (score 0):

some tips, you are not using your import http, so you can remove it, then you are using a custom middleware which is normally using 3 params `req, res, next`. And you can remove the dot in front of html => `app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);`

Then for your problem, it should be a configuration problem, not coming from nodeJS, I tried on my machine, and everything is ok with the code you sent (assuming you have your views in a directory called views, with the name index.html etc.)

So you should look at your nginx/apache configuration

Comment: I have contacted the guy that has created the guide that I have followed and he said that Nginx is not the one that is causing the problem but rather, express.js is the one that is causing the issue. Here is the issue that I raised: https://github.com/jlengstorf/code.lengstorf.com/issues/13

To add, here is the configuration of my nginx: http://pastebin.com/mBRLm1g9